# why would you use both a reverse proxy and a load balancer when you can just load balance with a reverse proxy?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I read that one of the uses of a proxy server is to load balance with it. But, I also read that google uses both a load balancer and a reverse proxy. I am trying to understand what the use of a load balancer is when you already use a reverse proxy.

I found this question asked in reverse: [Why do we need reverse proxy if we have load balancer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/998245/why-do-we-need-reverse-proxy-if-we-have-load-balancer)